# Open vscode as superuser ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, root, visual-studio-code

I have tried `sudo code --user-data-dir="~/.vscode-root"` but then I got the black screen when vscode was opened. It's any other way to open vscode as superuser?

Answer (score 0):

If the VSCode version is v1.58 or later, the
In addition to the `--user-data-dir` option, the `--no-sandbox` option is required.

In other words, the command is as follows:

```
 $ sudo code --user-data-dir="~/.vscode-root" --no-sandbox
```